# getting "Missing required parameter 'client_id'" error in react-google-login

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth, google-signin

I inserted my client id correctly and it did work

but suddenly it's not working until now even though I didn't change any codes in `<GoogleLogin />`

Also it works in blank React when I tested but not working in this project

exact error message is `Uncaught qw {message: "Missing required parameter 'client_id'", xM: true, stack: "gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Missing require…YZKdHMHzzbYNF1G7KSEIjXaBQQw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:1:15"}`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./CSS/Header.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { GoogleLogin } from "react-google-login";
export default function Header() {
  const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
  };
  return (
    <Router>
      <div id="header">
        <div id="id"></div>
        <h2 id="header_title">title</h2>
        <div id="contents">
          <h4 className="content">
            <Link
              to="/"
              onClick={() => {
                window.location.href = "/";
              }}
            >
              HOME
            </Link>
          </h4>
          <h4 className="content">
            <Link
              to="/history"
              onClick={() => {
                window.location.href = "/history";
              }}
            >
              History
            </Link>
          </h4>
          <GoogleLogin
            clientid=[myclientid]
            buttonText="Login"
            onSuccess={responseGoogle}
            isSignedIn={true}
            onFailure={responseGoogle}
            cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Client id should be like `clientid={myclientid}`

Comment: yes I inserted correctly but just deleted when posting here

Answer (score 2):

You should use `clientId` instead of `clientid` for the prop